# Merge multiple multi channel image

Tags: matlab

I try to merge multiple multi channels image into one image.
My image has 512x512 px and has 4 data-channels (16bits)
That I want to do is overlay image A with image B with image C, ...
for get the merged result.

I have checkout matlab function `imfuse` but it only works for 1 channels image or 3 channels image.

The real problem I want to solve is, I have a 3-dim data set with 4 channels and want to get how this set is locking from top, by reduse 3-dim model into a 2-dim image.

My data set display in 3d and convert channels into colors in RGB for display
[image: My data set display in 3d and convert channels into colors in RGB for display]

What I want, the result in 3d, and the more bottom thing is hidden by top layers.
[image: My data set display in 2d by rotate the 3d plot.]

Comment: Let me know if that duplicate is suitable... I think it is.  If not, I'll reopen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but no help for me, as I say, imfuse works only for grayscale and RGB image and not image with 4 data channels as in my case.

Comment: So you want to merge an image with `>= 3` channels?  How exactly did you want to merge them?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, In my mind, I think of this as a image with RGB, and when we merge more then two image, the first image will be hide of the laiter images part that not is transparent ,

Comment: How did you want to merge the two images together?  What method?  Average over each channel?

Comment: Unsure, witch method, but I think how I want the result, has upload some example image to display.

Comment: I'm confused. What do the 4 data channels correspond to in the final image? You've got a color image there, are each of those colors present in each data channel or is each channel a color, or ?